# How to get code from Facebook Authorization request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to pass the Facebook Authorization code as a value to my back-end during a sign in. I've figured out that I can generate a code by requesting  it via `https://www.facebook.com/v8.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=6**********&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/*****/***`

Which returns a url: `http://localhost:3000/****/******?code=AQDrfYDvQdrWxd*************nI6QfJrZqDBW-diVXr0vSWr7eDNyJ6axCPx_gYubndupibMHiI0gVnPT8I4cfun240_01DzweTsq7F7Hk7d1Vnrfl4F4YREjOAt8LZmk83EHKexsLQrs2QbbIki6u51m90tGbo_WzxUg5Q#_=_`

How do I get the code from this request by using Javascript or Axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the code you want to extract from the url you can do it like this.

```
const returnUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/****/******?code=AQDrfYDvQdrWxd*************nI6QfJrZqDBW-diVXr0vSWr7eDNyJ6axCPx_gYubndupibMHiI0gVnPT8I4cfun240_01DzweTsq7F7Hk7d1Vnrfl4F4YREjOAt8LZmk83EHKexsLQrs2QbbIki6u51m90tGbo_WzxUg5Q#_=_';
const url = new URL(returnUrl);
const code = url.searchParams.get('code');
console.log(code);
```

Comment: I have to go to the first irl, that one generates the code.

Comment: You want to send a GET request to that url? If it is in the browser you can do it by using fetch which is built in to all modern broswers.....for example fetch(yourURL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data)); If this is what you want i can put it in the answer.